# Regex capture single entry from log file when entry contains multiple line breaks

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm attempting to parse an Elasticsearch log file, but I'm getting hung up.  I can't seem to get it to break before the next line entry.  Here's a snippet of the log (I trimmed it down signifcantly):

```
[2014-09-03 07:47:40,088][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Server1] [my_index_name123][1], node[JLNzpIU9QRikVkfQyIFjCA], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@769a0c28] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [my_index_name123][1]: from[0],size[10],sort[<custom:"time_generated": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@7d4bfe4>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"time_generated":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"fields":["event_message"],"default_operator":"AND","query":null}}]}}}},"aggs":{"events_over_time":{"filter":{"range":{"time_generated":{"from":"2014-08-05T12:47:41.000Z","to":"2014-09-03T12:47:41.000Z"}}},"aggs":{"timeline":{"date_histogram":{"field":"time_generated","interval":"day"}}}}}}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:634)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [my_index_name123] query_string must be provided with a [query]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:622)
    ... 11 more
[2014-09-03 07:47:40,088][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Server1] [my_index_name123][0], node[JLNzpIU9QRikVkfQyIFjCA], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@769a0c28]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [my_index_name123][0]: from[0],size[10],sort[<custom:"time_generated": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@6392f9f7>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"time_generated":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"fields":["event_message"],"default_operator":"AND","query":null}}]}}}},"aggs":{"events_over_time":{"filter":{"range":{"time_generated":{"from":"2014-08-05T12:47:41.000Z","to":"2014-09-03T12:47:41.000Z"}}},"aggs":{"timeline":{"date_histogram":{"field":"time_generated","interval":"day"}}}}}}]]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [my_index_name123] query_string must be provided with a [query]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:622)
    ... 11 more
[2014-09-03 07:47:40,088][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Server1] All shards failed for phase: [query]
[2014-09-03 07:47:40,088][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Server1] [my_index_name123][4], node[JLNzpIU9QRikVkfQyIFjCA], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@769a0c28] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [my_index_name123][4]: from[0],size[10],sort[<custom:"time_generated": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.LongValuesComparatorSource@6cb38cdb>!]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"time_generated":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"fields":["event_message"],"default_operator":"AND","query":null}}]}}}},"aggs":{"events_over_time":{"filter":{"range":{"time_generated":{"from":"2014-08-05T12:47:41.000Z","to":"2014-09-03T12:47:41.000Z"}}},"aggs":{"timeline":{"date_histogram":{"field":"time_generated","interval":"day"}}}}}}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:634)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [my_index_name123] query_string must be provided with a [query]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:622)
    ... 11 more
```

Here's a regex pattern I've been testing:

```
(?<=(\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\]))([\d\s\p{L}\p{P}\p{S}]+)(?=\n\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\])
```

The pattern matches every log entry but the last one.  I assume that's because of the lookahead on the end.  I've been staring at this for a while, but I can't seem to come up with a way to just get it to match a single entry.  I'm using PCRE.  Hopefully someone has stronger regex-fu than me.

Comment: I know its a little off topic, but why not using logstash for that, there's a multiline plugin really great to capture this kind of logs when combined with grok plugin for catpures. And I don't understand why you use a lookahead at the end of the match, Do you wish to capture the whole file ?

Comment: You're right I could use Logstash which would likely do this for me.  But in this case I'm opting to do the parsing and storing myself.  I like the challenge. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two changes that need to be made.

1) make the capture group quantifier lazy so it only goes up to the next timestamp

```
([\d\s\p{L}\p{P}\p{S}]+?)
```

2) add an alternation to the lookahead to match a possible end of string

```
(?=(\n\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\]|$))
```

Here's the full regex:

```
(?<=(\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\]))([\d\s\p{L}\p{P}\p{S}]+?)(?=(\n\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\]|$))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I didn't even think of making the quantifier lazy.  I didn't realize I could do an alternation with the end marker either.